# How to create a new row if new row is create in another tbale?

Tags: mysql

**I have one table like this:**

```
create table submit_data (id int not null primary key auto_increment,
Customer varchar(240))
```

**How can I create a table for the following instruction:**

If new data is inserted to `submit_data` then..

Create new row into another table and just take the new created `id`

**This is where I got to:**

```
create table copy_data (id
```

All I need is to take the `id` from `submit_data`

**Here is my desired output if 2 lines are added into `submit_data`:**

```
id
1
2
```

Comment: Hint: Use triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a seperate table with a column ID and then setting a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) on the submit_data table to insert or update the new table on an insert event.

So something along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE copy_data (id int not null primary key default 0)
```

And the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER copy_id AFTER INSERT ON submit_data FOR EACH ROW
       INSERT IGNORE INTO copy_data VALUES(NEW.ID);
```